# Sql server with Bonobo GIT

Tags: sql-server, git, bonobo

I have configured Bonobo GIT and it's working fine with SQL Lite.

Can we user SQL Server with Bonobo GIT? If, Yes then where can I find the ready made database?

Comment: What advantages were you hoping for from SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can run it with SQL Server, and it will create the database for you, but personally (as someone who's done some work on Bonobo) I wouldn't recommend it - the database tends to be very small anyway, and you'll get no significant advantage from using SQL Server.

Comment: Generally yes. SQL Server performance (indexes...) could be relevant in larger applications, say >100 concurrent users interacting with bonobo (not coding for hours without pushing/fetching) to name a ballpark. I'd also consider SQL Server if you have the tools to look into the database and run queries against it, like to generate some statistics. You can always use LINQPad with the SQL Lite Adapter though :-)

Comment: The Bonobo database only has user account details and repo permissions  in it - it doesn't contain anything to do with activity on those repos or any kind of repo content - of course you can always come up with a set of numbers and a usage profile where SQLite wouldn't be suitable, but I think they would be huge, and I suspect there might be other bits of the server creaking before the user database.

Comment: The point I was hoping to make was "you can always use another db backend, but you most likely won't need it". I've seen the db schema ;-) and to be SQLite the bottleneck here, you need *a lot* of concurrent auth stuff and thus a hell of a lot more users. TFS on the other hand also stores the git artifacts into the database - which is causes magnitudes more db load and thus won't work in a production environment.

Comment: for starters your can manage the database with the studio, without having to pay for SQLite driver